# Spam in Zimbra OpenRelay

Tags: email, postfix

First apologize me for the grammar, english isn't my native language.
The problem I have is users from our local zimbra mail are getting spam messages from other email addresses who don't exist, like annymous172167@ourdomain

I found that the problem can be OpenRelay in postfix configuration.
I did this test http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/381/send_mail_via_telnet_test_for_open_relay/ and found that I can send emails via telnet without any authentication.
To resolve the problem, I tried to change the postfix configuration.

My original conf file (**/opt/zimbra/postfix-2.10.3.2z/conf/main.cf**) was

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
  check_sender_access 
    regexp:/opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/tag_as_originating.re, 
  permit_mynetworks, 
  permit_sasl_authenticated, 
  permit_tls_clientcerts, 
  check_sender_access 
    regexp:/opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/tag_as_foreign.re, 
  check_sender_access hash:/opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/access_table
```

And I tried to change to:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
  reject_unknown_sender_domain
```

But when I run `$postfix reload` the configuration come back to the original one, without any changes.

Comment: I found the solution, thank you all https://www.jorgedelacruz.es/2014/04/03/zimbra-seguridad-i-parte/